# actualizar registro e ignorar los campos de tipo unique en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación

Hola tengo elsiguente problema: en el metodo update tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
 public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
{

 $user->update($request->all())

}
```

en el archivo web:

```
  Route::put('edit/{user}', 'UsersController@update')->name('users.update');
```

esta es la linea de mi usersRequest:

```
'email' => ['required','email',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->id)],
```

y mi formulario:

```
{{ Form::model($user, ['route' => ['users.update', $user->id],'method' => 'put']) }}
            @include('users.formUsers')
            <a href="{{ route('users.index') }}" class="btn btn-secondary border-dark mr-md-3">{{ trans('app.btn_cancel') }} <span class="icon-cross2"></span></a>
            <button id="btnUpdateUser" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ trans('app.btn_save_changes') }} <span class="icon-save"></span></button>

        {{ Form::close() }}
```

y siempre veo los errores de validacion que el correo ya esta en uso

espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Si el parámetro de la ruta es `user`, prueba con `Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user)` en vez de `$this->id`

Comment: gracias, fue uno de los intentos, pero le di solucion con campos que vienen desde el form que serias las propiedades del objeto Rule::unique('users','email')->ignore($this->email, 'email')

Comment: no entiendo el punto de usar laravel para usar sql, en codeigniter se ocupa pdo aún usando código sql normalizado

Comment: ¿a que se refiere con normalizado?